# Error: connect ETIMEDOUT

Tags: mysql, nodejs, ubuntu

Estoy tratando de conectarme mediante nodejs a mysql, y cada vez que lo ejecuto me salta el siguiente error:

```
Error: connect ETIMEDOUT ipservidor:3306
at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1129:14)
--------------------
at Protocol._enqueue (C:\Users\Eze\Desktop\mysqltest\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:144:48)
at Protocol.handshake (C:\Users\Eze\Desktop\mysqltest\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:51:23)
at Connection.connect (C:\Users\Eze\Desktop\mysqltest\node_modules\mysql\lib\Connection.js:119:18)
at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Eze\Desktop\mysqltest\app.js:11:5)
at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:971:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1011:10)
at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:822:32)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:730:14)
at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1051:12)
at internal/main/run_main_module.js:16:11 {
errno: -4039,
code: 'ETIMEDOUT',
syscall: 'connect',
address: 'ipservidor',
port: 3306,
fatal: true
}
The solution is:  undefined
```

Este es mi código:

```
const mysql = require('mysql');
const con = mysql.createConnection({
  host: 'ipservidor',
  user: 'user',
  password: 'pass',
  database: 'database',
  connectTimeout: 30000
});
con.connect();

con.query('SELECT * from fichar', function(err, rows, fields) {
  if(err) console.log(err);
  console.log('The solution is: ', rows);
  con.end();
});
```

He comprobado que este abierto el puerto para la conexión, el firewall esta desactivado en el servidor (es un server de pruebas) y no consigo conectarme.

Alguna idea?

Comment: Desde la terminal o cualquier otro gestor puedes conectarte?

Comment: Des del propio servidor me puedo conectar sin problemas @EugeniBejan

Comment: Has mirando que el servidor escuche por la ip publica? Y no solo localhost

Comment: Si. Es un servidor en AWS y me he conectado mediante SSH con la ip publica

Comment: Si, pero ssh es un servicio aparte, lo que puede pasar es que tu servidor de base de datos no este escuchando en tu ip publica. Mira el archivo `/etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf`

Comment: El bind-address esta en 0.0.0.0, no se si es esa la linea que hay que mirar

Comment: Si, esta perfecto entonces

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/101742/discussion-between-eugeni-bejan-and-sphere).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

He encontrado aquí la solución: https://mariolurig.com/coding/connect-remotely-mysql-database-amazon-ec2-server/

Gracias a Eugeni!

Comment: Y cual es la solución?